# How to append PDF using itext 5

Tags: pdf, append, itext

i try append my PDF on new ITEXT document but it's not possible, i create document which i would like add. How to do it from the document level? need to somehow convert to bytes?

```
  String inputFilePath = "C:\\Users\\yol\\Desktop\\90-B1-1C-91-7D-13\\historyPDF\\07-12-2019 01-10-36-700.pdf"; // Existing file
    String outputFilePath = "C:\\Users\\yol\\Desktop\\90-B1-1C-91-7D-13\\historyPDF\\07-12-2019 01-10-36-700_new.pdf"; // New file

    Document document = new Document();
    OutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(outputFilePath));
    PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(inputFilePath);
    PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, fos);
    pdfStamper.insertPage(pdfReader.getNumberOfPages() + 1, pdfReader.getPageSizeWithRotation(1));


    PdfContentByte pdfContentByte = pdfStamper.getUnderContent(pdfReader.getNumberOfPages());

    pdfContentByte.beginText();
    pdfContentByte.setFontAndSize(BaseFont.createFont
                    (BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN,
                            BaseFont.CP1257,
                            BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED
                    )
            , 12);
    pdfContentByte.setTextMatrix(35, 760);
    document.open();
    Chapter chapter = new Chapter("", 0);
    chapter.setNumberDepth(0);
    Paragraph time = new Paragraph("");
    Paragraph date = new Paragraph("");
    Paragraph type = new Paragraph("");


    chapter.add(time);
    chapter.add(date);
    chapter.add(type);
    document.add(chapter);





    pdfContentByte.endText();
    document.close();
    pdfStamper.close();
    pdfReader.close();
```

Comment: Don't try to do all at once. First create a new PDF with your new content using a `Document` & `PdfWriter`, writing to a temporary location (in the file system or in memory). Then use a new `Document` & `PdfCopy` to merge all documents you want to bundle in a single one.